# Metal on iOS: Is using vertex instances somehow wasteful?

Tags: ios, graphics, metal

I have implemented a Bezier curve in Metal, in the hopes of achieving great performance. While the speed is pretty good, I am seeing numbers **far** lower than expected performance (relative to the triangles/sec specs of the various devices).

[image]

Specifically, I am confused about that behavior of the GPU when I change certain parameters. I am rendering thousands of Bezier curves using `drawIndexedPrimitives()`. Each instance represents a single curve, and the number of vertexes per instance represents how many triangles are used for each curve.

The only buffer I am passing to my vertex shader is a per-instance parameter buffer with no per-vertex data being passed. The actual Bezier curve points are calculated within the vertex shader **without any per-vertex data being loaded**.

Here is what puzzles me: **I can dramatically increase the number of vertexes per instance without affecting performance much, but upping the number of instances directly increases the GPU frame processing time.**

My expectation was that the GPU shouldn't care whether I am adding instances or vertexes -- more vertexes means more work. What am I missing?

## Actual performance numbers:

For one performance example, in terms of triangles/sec the iPad Pro appears to be achieving around 2000 curves consisting of 200 triangles each at around 40FPS (around 25ms/frame). That equates a roughly 16M triangles/sec fillrate, which is significantly below the expected performance for that device.

On the same iPad Pro, doubling the number of triangles-per-curve from 200 to 400 only increases the per-frame time to around 31ms. That's a 24% increase after we basically doubled the GPU's workload! If we double the number of curves instead (keeping the per-curve triangle count at 200), performance drops to around 47ms per frame.

Note that the GPU has to render the exact same number of triangles in both of these cases -- what is so different about them?

The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/eldade/ios_metal_bezier_renderer).

Comment: One thing that occurs to me is that doubling the triangles per curve presumably keeps the number of fragments being processed constant and may result in substantially fewer than twice the number of triangles in the average tile (since each triangle is smaller), while doubling the number of instances doubles the number of fragments processed and also doubles the number of triangles in the average tile. I'm not taking into account the very significant effects of early Z and hidden-surface removal, but it seems that these scenarios _should_ have rather different performance characteristics.

Comment: I'm curious what the numbers look like when the vertex shader only emits degenerate triangles (e.g. by setting the curve width to 0), as well as what happens if the curves are positioned to keep overdraw constant between the two scenarios.

Comment: Increasing the instance count increases the size of buffer 0, which may prevent caching or the like. If you keep the instance count the same but double the size of `struct BezierParameters` with padding, does that have the same effect? Have you considered the use of `stage_in` input and the vertex buffer layout stuff? That might allow Metal to fetch the per-instance data more efficiently.